# android sqlite select avg multiple columns

Tags: android, sqlite, average

I have a problem with a query of sqlite. I want to do is the average of two columns and place the result in a new column. example:

```
id | max_ma  |  max_ta  | avg_max (new column)

1  | 100     |  102     |   101  ==> (100+102)/2

2 |  100     |  null    |   100 ==> (100+0)/1 INGNORE NULL
```

wrong code:

```
public Cursor list() {
String lista_ge = "SELECT *, AVG(tr_max_m + tr_max_t) AS media_max FROM bdt_registro ORDER BY tr_fecha DESC, _id DESC";
return db.rawQuery(lista_ge, null);
}
```

or

```
public Cursor list() {
String lista_ge = "SELECT *, ((tr_max_m + tr_max_t)/COUNT(*)) AS media_max FROM bdt_registro ORDER BY tr_fecha DESC, _id DESC";
return db.rawQuery(lista_ge, null);
}
```

Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best approach will be to use a lot of cases:

```
SELECT max_ma, max_ta,
  CASE WHEN max_ma IS NULL THEN
    CASE WHEN max_ta IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE max_ta END
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN max_ta IS NULL THEN max_ma
    ELSE (max_ma + max_ta) / 2 END
  END avg_max
FROM user_address
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/75bf5/1).

By the way, I noticed you were trying to use `AVG`. If you're wondering how you could have used that function then this will give you an idea. It won't be faster than the previous approach because it adds more calculation, though:

```
SELECT id,
  max(CASE WHEN kind = 1 THEN aMax END) max_ma,
  max(CASE WHEN kind = 2 THEN aMax END) max_ta,
  avg(aMax) aMax
FROM (
  SELECT id, max_ma aMax, 1 kind FROM user_address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, max_ta, 2 FROM user_address
) s
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [COALESCE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function:

```
SELECT *,
(COALESCE(tr_max_m, tr_max_t, 0) + COALESCE(tr_max_t, tr_max_m, 0)) / 2 AS media_max
FROM
bdt_registro ORDER BY tr_fecha DESC, _id DESC
```

- If both are non_`NULL` you get: `(tr_max_t + tr_max_m) / 2`
- If `tr_max_m` is `NULL` you get: `(tr_max_t + tr_max_t) / 2 = tr_max_t`
- If `tr_max_t` is `NULL` you get: `(tr_max_m + tr_max_m) / 2 = tr_max_m`
- If both are `NULL` you get: `(0 + 0) / 2 = 0`

Comment: Haha, funny way to calculate this.

Comment: @MostyMostacho I decided to use `COALESCE` before I had a solution in mind :P

Comment: thank you all. now it works.
did not know the function COALESCE

good code:

String lista_ge = "SELECT *, (COALESCE(tr_max_m, 0) + COALESCE(tr_max_t, 0)) /(COALESCE(tr_max_m/tr_max_m, 0) + COALESCE(tr_max_t/tr_max_t, 0)) AS media_max FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on function `IFNULL` and...

... "un-aggregated" aggregated function `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *,
    (IFNULL(max_ma, 0)+IFNULL(max_ta, 0))/(COUNT(max_ma)+COUNT(max_ta)) AS avg_max
FROM bdt_registro
GROUP BY id;
```

... `CASE`:

```
SELECT *,
    (IFNULL(max_ma, 0)+IFNULL(max_ta, 0)) / (CASE WHEN max_ma IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + CASE WHEN max_ta IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS avg_max
FROM bdt_registro;
```

[» SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9f3c7/1)